# Filling gap between wooden window frame and glass

Tags: windows

We recently bought a house from 1973 which has been very much neglected.
The windows got wood rot and now we are dealing with this big gap where the caulk (and foam insulation?) came loose.

I need some help and ideas on how to fill this.
Fill it with caulk? Foam strip? The gap is at its largest 7 mm, and smallest 1 mm and still got some foam looking stuff.

[image: window pane gap]

[image: small gap]

Comment: Does the window frost up when it is cold ? Seal in glass maybe broken. If not seal the outside with caulk. Use the foam in the big gaps, and a fine bead on the rest of window.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what we're looking at; a diagram would really help.

Comment: Thank you, Robert, that is just what I was hoping to hear!
And no it doesn't frost up. It does, however, condense on the bottom in the winter due to lack of ventilation in the house.